# Drivers for a Lexmark X4690

Tags: drivers, printing

Have anyone got a Lexmark X4690 to work under Ubuntu?
Or is the only option to install Windows on a VM?

Answer (score 1):

From lexmark [here](http://support.lexmark.com/index?page=content&id=OS4&locale=en&userlocale=EN_UK) that particular printer is supported.

Deb file can be downloaded from [here](http://support.lexmark.com/index?locale=en&page=product&productCode=LEXMARK_X4690&segment=SUPPORT&userlocale=EN_UK&frompage=null#1)

Are you having any issues installing this printer - or is the above information the bit you were missing?

Comment: Thanks I couldn't find anything on the UK site were I was looking, I'll try that over the weekend and see if it works.

Comment: Just get a message saying "Install failed" no details or anything.